# When was Donald Trump's first visit to his mother's birthplace, the Isle of Lewis?

Tags: scotland

United States President Donald Trump's mother Mary Anne MacLeod was a Gaelic-speaking Scotswoman from the Isle of Lewis in Scotland. After emigrating to the US she frequently visited the island of her birth. Her son Donald has also visited, most recently in 2008. [According to the Scotsman newspaper](https://www.scotsman.com/news/uk-news/donald-trumps-relative-hes-never-given-penny-his-mothers-scottish-community-1407740) he also visited the island on one previous occasion, when he was a child. Since he was born in 1946, that would have been some time in the period 1946-64.

When was Donald Trump's first visit to Lewis? What has been written about it?

Comment: Hello! As the Scotsman seems to have limited online presence (limited articles per unit of time), you'd be best served by quoting the specific paragraph in your post as well. I also made the title a bit more succinct (please revert if you mind). I would also suggest using the tag [tag:date] which is kind-of linked to questions about the dates of events.

Answer (score 4):

There might not be clear records of it:

> Mary Anne Trump's billionaire son Donald visited the house in which his mother grew up, and his cousins in 2008.
>
> On that trip, the now president-elect said he had been to Lewis once before as "a three or four-year-old" but could remember little about it.
>
> <sup>—BBC, [Donald Trump's mother: From a Scottish island to New York's elite](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-38648877)</sup>

Given [Donald Trump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump) was born in June 14, 1946, this would mean it was around 1949-50.

I tried for more specific searches around this time period, but looking into Trump and these years links people to [the Hebrides Revival](http://www.revival-library.org/index.php/pensketches-menu/historical-revivals/the-hebrides-revival) which seems to overshadow any possible remaining mentions of the visit.

Comment: Thanks for this. It would be good if we could get a source for a pre-2008 visit that does not rely on a statement made by Donald Trump himself. There is also the "pancake theft" allegation which requires him being on Lewis. It sounds as though he was a child at the time, but statements attributed to Alice Mackay are not clear on that point and I am not sure they are fully reliable anyway given that I have yet to find corroboration for her assertion that Mary Anne Trump spent months on Lewis every summer after she got married (although there is corroboration for her having visited a lot).

Comment: @ool: Yes. I think a non-standard approach is required as for most people writing about him, it's not very interesting. Therefore, I tried to see if Mary Anne Trump's visits had been recorded but I didn't notice anything of the kind.